# Self-custodial Login by Web3Auth Dialog

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I'm implementing Safe Auth Kit into our dApp. But on the official demo site, there is this login dialog with all kinds of sign-in options. But in the GitHub repo, I don't see how can i set these options. All I get is the SafeAuth Dialog with only the google sign-in option.

My question is how do I implement the Web3Auth login dialog with Auth Kit?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the first screenshot you shared shows an outdated version of the Auth Kit. The second one is the latest version. If you want more social auth providers, you can create your own implementation based on the [AuthKitBasePack](https://docs.safe.global/sdk-auth-kit/reference/auth-kit-base-pack) classes. The SafeAuthPack currently only supports Google as a provider.

Hope it helps! Best, Louis